# angular , jquery not able to compare the array in controller

Tags: javascript

unable to get into the for loop and generate an alert or log to find the duplicate element

```
var a1=['sdfsdf','sdfs','rere','112'];   
var a2=['333','666','888','112'];    

var resultant=[];     

resultant=a1.concat(a2);    
console.log(resultant);           // able to find the a1 and a2 merged     
      console.log(resultant.length);     // able to find the length ., 
for(var i=0;i<resultant.length;i++)
{

     console.log(resultant.length);      

    var k=i;      
    alert("test");         
   if(resultant[k]==resultant[k+1])     
    {    
     console.log(resultant[i]);     
     console.log(resultant[i+1]);      
       alert("duplicate");     
     }    
}    

https://jsfiddle.net/h9945394143/2m3dk553/5/
```

Comment: What is your question? For help, see "[How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo - resultant.lenght, [check the spelling for length, updated plunkr here](https://jsfiddle.net/newjavaonemahesh/3qr3h45u/1/)

```
console.log(resultant.length);
for(var i=0;i<resultant.length;i++){
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
var a1=['sdfsdf','sdfs','rere','112'];
var a2=['333','666','888','112'];
for (var i = 0; i<a2.length; i++) {
    var arrlen = a1.length;
    for (var j = 0; j<arrlen; j++) {
        if (a2[i] == a1[j]) {
            alert(a2[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**ECMA Script 6**

```js
var a1 = ['sdfsdf', 'sdfs', 'rere', '112'];
var a2 = ['333', '666', '888', '112'];

var resultant = a1.concat(a2);

let seen = new Set();
var hasDuplicates = resultant.some(function(currentObject) {
    return seen.size === seen.add(currentObject).size;
});

console.log(hasDuplicates);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. this will work,

```js
var a1=['sdfsdf','sdfs','rere','112'];   
var a2=['333','666','888','112'];    

var resultant=[];   

resultant=a1.concat(a2);    
alert(resultant);
alert(resultant.length);
for(var i=0;i<resultant.length;i++)
{
   alert(resultant[i]);
   for(var k=i+1;k<resultant.length;k++)
   {
      if(resultant[i]==resultant[k])     
      {      
   alert("duplicate");     
      }
   }
}
```